# Is there a way for me to send the 404 page using the Next.js api routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Basically, I have an API route */api/signin.js*. And I want to accept *post* requests and return the 404 page when I get a *get* request. I haven't found any way to return the 404 page without doing something like a redirect. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
export default async function Signin(req, res) {
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////// //
    // Here is where I want to send the 404 custom 404.js page //
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////// //
    if(req.method === "GET") {
        return res.status(404).send();
    }
    
    if(req.method !== "POST") {
        return res.status(404).send();
    }

    try {
        const { cookies, body } = req;
        console.log(req.cookies);

        // Signin logic...
        
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ err: "Internal server error" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you could use ReactDOMServer's [`renderToString`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) function

> Render a React element to its initial HTML. React will return an HTML string. You can use this method to generate HTML on the server and send the markup down on the initial request for faster page loads and to allow search engines to crawl your pages for SEO purposes.

or ReactDOMServer's [`renderToStaticMarkup`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) function

> Similar to renderToString, except this doesn’t create extra DOM attributes that React uses internally, such as data-reactroot. This is useful if you want to use React as a simple static page generator, as stripping away the extra attributes can save some bytes.

```
// pages/404.js
export default function Custom404() {
  return <h1>404 - Page Not Found</h1>;
}
```

```
// pages/api/signin.js
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import NotFound from "../404"; // import your 404 page

export default function Signin(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send(ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<NotFound />));
  }

  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }

  try {
    const { cookies, body } = req;
    console.log(req.cookies);

    // Signin logic...
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ err: "Internal server error" });
  }
}
```

This way you can send a `404` status code and send an html representation back without a redirect.

Comment: I tried using the _renderToStaticMarkup_, but the only problem was that **this prevented any imported css modules from working** (as Next.js forces you to use with the _name.module.css_ naming convention). In the end, if there isn't any way to get around that, I could just use the `<style>` tag inside of the jsx and put all the css in there.

*edit:* I forgot to mention that the global styles imported into the __app.js_ file also don't work.